# A cross-posted question's answer making the initial a bit trivial

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

In a fairly old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334320/array-subset-optimization-with-composite-aggregate-functions) of mine, posted on Stack Overflow, I was encouraged to ask for help on MathOverflow. It did make sense since the question was mostly maths related, but I was still looking for a PHP way to accomplish the task.

The [cross-posted question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306248/subset-optimization-with-composite-aggregate-functions) was answered and I finally accepted it. However, I'm left with the initial question on Stack Overflow which has a few votes and favorites (so I probably shouldn't delete it in case people found it helpful) but has an answer that I simply can't accept; the maths part isn't properly answered at all and therefore the PHP bit is pointless.

So, should I write my own PHP code that uses the answer on MathOverflow and give credit to it, and accept that?

Since it should stay related to programming, I suppose I couldn't simply post a Community answer linking to the cross-posted Q&A?

Comment: I would say yes, add the answer and accept it

Comment: @TemaniAfif the only thing that itches me though is I can definitely come up with some PHP for the math logic, but my code may not be optimal, which is the main point of the question. I'll check if I can come up with something acceptable though.

Comment: "Optimal" is relative.  If you post something that works reasonably well, others may be able to suggest improvements or use that as a springboard to create a more optimized version.  It is better to have something less-than-perfect than to have nothing at all.

Comment: God, not a single upvote on MathOverflow?  And some people think Stack Overflow is stingy with up-voting, jesus christ.

Comment: You can definitely (maybe even: should have) at least post a comment linking the MO post

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Does current answer actually answer *programming* portion of the question? - If yes - accept and add comment with link to your math Q&A pair (you may also ask answerer to inline the link into the question).

Otherwise post your own complete answer with PHP code and link to MathOverflow Q&A. Definitely don't copy-paste MathOverflow post to SO as target audiences are very different. You don't need to post your answer as community wiki unless your post is just compilation of other posts (which would not be case here).